# Find the Cosets of Subgroup $\langle 3 \rangle $ of $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

*"A Book of Abstract Algebra"* presents the following exercise:

> Describe the cosets of the subgroups:
>
> The subgroup $\langle 3 \rangle $ of $\mathbb{Z}$

Given that $H=\langle 3 \rangle $, I tried to figure out the cosets:

$$H=\lbrace 0,1,2 \rbrace$$
$$H+1=\lbrace 1,2,0 \rbrace$$
$$H+2=\lbrace 2,0,1 \rbrace$$

Since $H=H+1=H+2$, it seems to me that there's a single coset.

Please confirm, clarify or correct my attempt at figuring out the cosets of $\langle 3 \rangle$.

Comment: What makes you think that $H = \{0, 1, 2 \}$?

Comment: Is $<3>$ the same as $\mathbb{Z}_3$?

Comment: $\langle 3 \rangle$ in $\Bbb Z$  is the subgroup of all integer multiples of 3. It is not a finite set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$H\ne\{0,1,2\}$, $H=\{3n:n\in\Bbb Z\}$. That should help.

Comment: So a sample of $H=\lbrace 0, 3, 6, ... \rbrace$. So, $H+1 = \lbrace 1,4,7,... \rbrace = \lbrace 1 \rbrace$. $H+2 = \lbrace 2, 5, 8 \rbrace = \lbrace 2 \rbrace$. At $H+3=H$. So, the cosets of $H$ are $H, H+1, H+2$. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea.

Comment: Thank you. And `that's the idea` means it's correct? Could you please let me know if I'm not properly and fully answering the exercise? It's self-study, not homework for school.

Comment: Yes, This is correct.

Answer (score 2):

$H$ is the subgroup generated by $3$, that is, the subset of $\Bbb Z$ of the numbers that can be obtained adding or substracting $3$. This is
$$H=\{\ldots,-9,-6,-3,0,3,6,9,\ldots\}$$